# Как правильнее? Пара минут

Tags: выбор-слов

«Не прошла и пара минут», «не прошло и пары минут»? Или вообще иной вариант?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:  ***не прошло и пары минут***, сравнить: ***прошла пара минут.***

При  отрицании используется **родительный** падеж, что особенно характерно для **отвлеченных** существительных (не хватает времени).

Но форма Р.п. не может быть подлежащим в двусоставном предложении, поэтому используется **безличное** односоставное предложение, а в этом случае форма прошедшего времени  соответствует  среднему роду: *не прошло*.

Примеры:

**Прошла пара** минут, и ворота со скрежетом отворились. [Андрей Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи (2000)]

**Не прошло и пары минут**, как он услышал какой-то гул. [Михаил Тырин. «Будет немножечко больно» (2014)]